# CSS external file doesn't make an effect

Tags: html, css

I am  new in CSS so am practice it.
I wrote a css file and a html file in order to see the effect of external CSS file on my html page but no change observed.

Here my codes

style.css

```
p {
  Color:red;    
}
```

index.html

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html> 
      <head>
        <meta charset ="UTF-8">
        <title>Css Syntax </title>
        <link rel ="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/CSS">
      </head>
      <body> 
        <p>this is nirmal paragtne</p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem using that code. The most likely explanation is that you got the URL wrong.

Comment: I [tested it here](https://jsfiddle.net/ka44807h/) and came to the same conclusion as @Quentin. Your `href` is probably not linking to the correct path.

Comment: Does the `index.html` and `style.css` in the same directory?

Comment: @Tesseract yes in one directory

Comment: Let me rephrase, both file are in the same level within the directory?

Comment: Yes they are in a folder called CSS !

Comment: What text editor are you using?

Comment: I am using notepad++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked my code in **firefox** browser and it works fine

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be working fine for me.. If it's in the same directory maybe you could try checking your filenames if there's no typing error?